# Javascript result not as expectecd with css

Tags: javascript, css

This code works perfectly as I expected but the problem is when I refresh the page the t_con stays in absolute which should be fixed and when I resize the window less than 980px it is in absolute like what I need and if I resize again more than 980px it goes fixed.

I need it to stay fixed from start. I don't know why it is in absolute at first.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="t_con">
    <div id="t">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#t_con {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#t {
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #976398;
    width: 980px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Javascript CODE

```
window.onresize = function(){
    var header = document.getElementById('t');
    var window_width = document.body.offsetWidth;
    if(window_width < 980) {
        header.style.position = "absolute";
    } else {
        header.style.position = "fixed";
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong in here? And I don't want to use jQuery for this. So please do not suggest it. The reason I don't like jQuery is it already takes 90kb plus the code we are trying to execute.

Comment: you should love jQuery... It is awesome, easy and efficient....

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `window.onresize` twice so your first function will never be called.

Try:

```
window.onresize = function(){               
    document.getElementById('t_con').style.position = window.outerWidth < 980 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
    document.getElementById('t').style.position = document.body.offsetWidth < 980 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
}
```

Comment: i edited my code. i have another problem if i disable javascript i need to refresh the page to make to make it absolute like in my css. Is there a way to do it without page refresh?

Comment: Ho are you disabling your javascript? Do you mean removing the event handler?

Comment: disabling javascript in browser. some user will have their javascript disabled. for them it should be absolute without page refresh.

Comment: i run a test of this code and it works properly then i disabled javascript in browser and it stays fixed till i refresh page after refresh it turns absolute. i want this to happen without refresh

Comment: I would add `position:absolute;` to your header so it's default when js is disabled. Other than that you can't do much about a user disabling javascript while on your site. Why would they anyway?

Comment: i think you dont understand what i say. it is default by position:absolute;. Try this code in your browser. resize ur browser and it works fine. then disable your browser javascript and see what happens if window is less than 980px it stays in fixed position till page refresh. which is what i dont want it to do. it should come to absoulte without page refresh.

Comment: If the user disables javascript in their browser while the position is fixed, there is nothing you can do. I doubt that a user would do that often.